# How to fill up a textfield exactly as the selected option from the select list..?

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a jsp page.
I have a numeric select list. Whose has some default value but that is dynamically generated.
I also have a text field.
I want the text field should be filled automatically exactly as the selected option from the select list. I am using jquery to do it.

But i see when the jsp page load, the select list is there with its default value but the text field is blank. text field getting filled with selected option only when i change the option. I want that when the page load the text field get also filled with the dynamically generated option as with the select list.

My code of jquery inside script tag is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#select_id").change(function() {
                    $("#textfield_id").val($("#select_id option:selected").text());
                });});
```

Can any one suggest what should i do ?

Comment: Can some one solve this problem as well.. thanks.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641662/doccookie-is-not-getting-saved-instantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#select_id").change(function() {

         // this -> refers to the select field

        $("#textfield_id").val( this.value );
        // or
        $("#textfield_id").val( $('option:selected', this).text() );
    }).change(); // .change() is for trigger an initial change event after page load
                 // to update the textfield value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the name suggests, [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) will only be fired when the value of the element changes -- simply initialize the text-field to whatever the value of the drop-down list is at DOM ready before you bind to the change event. Also, consider using the [jQuery `.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method for getting/setting the value of form elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#textfield_id").val($("#select_id").val());

    $("#select_id").change(function() {
        $("#textfield_id").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```